# ruby sort_by! for array of objects

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

Okay, I KNOW I'm just doing something dumb here, but I just cannot get this to work.

I have an opportunity object

```
class Opportunity
  attr_accessor :effort
  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(effort,value)
    # set values to 1 + the Rayleigh distribution (rounded) 
    @effort = 1 + (effort * Math.sqrt(0-2*Math.log(1-rand()))).round
    @value = 1 + (value * Math.sqrt(0-2*Math.log(1-rand()))).round
  end
end
```

I push a set of these onto an array (that's a property of another object) and then I want to sort those by specific properties (like effort)

```
    # Order the working backlog
    #  (see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.3/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21)
    puts workingBacklog.backlog[0].effort
    workingBacklog.backlog.sort_by! {|opA,opB| opA.effort <=> opB.effort }
```

Here's sample output...

```
6
3cmc.rb:57:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `effort' for 
nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from 3cmc.rb:57:in `each'
    from 3cmc.rb:57:in `sort_by'
    from 3cmc.rb:57:in `sort_by!'
    from 3cmc.rb:57:in `block in <main>'
    from 3cmc.rb:51:in `each'
    from 3cmc.rb:51:in `<main>'
```

So I KNOW there's an array of non-NULL objects there because that "6" on the first line of output is non-Null. But right after that it looks like the proverbial wheels come off. What the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sort` method requires a comparison block (a vs. b) but the `sort_by` method only takes one argument, the element being sorted, and you're expected to return a transformed version if necessary, the way you want it sorted.

In your case it's this:

```
backlog.sort_by! { |e| e.effort }
```

Or more concisely:

```
backlog.sort_by!(&:effort)
```

Your original code would work if you use the correct method:

```
backlog.sort! {|opA,opB| opA.effort <=> opB.effort }
```

Where that's a lot more code than the `sort_by` alternative, but it does the job just the same. Generally `sort_by` performs better, it only transforms once per sort pass. The other function must transform once per *comparison*, of which there are usually a lot more than entries in an array, especially at larger array sizes.

> **NOTE:** In Ruby capital letters have significant contextual meaning, so variable and method names should be in `lower_case` only form. Capitals are reserved for `ClassName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` situations.

Comment: Yup! I got the wrong method on the array. I knew this was dumb.

Comment: For the record, I'm planning on building MUCH more complex comparison functions for sorting the array. But I wanted to get a SUPER simple version working first before I start layering on complexity.

Comment: That's fair. Just keep in mind that `sort_by` operates *N* times and `sort` operates on average *N x log(N)* times, which can be a lot more. In almost all cases `sort_by` is the way to go. It's when you need to write very complex tie-breaking rules that the other comes into play, but if you can express each entry as a sortable value, which can include arrays (e.g. `[ a.effort, a.tie_breaker ]`) then `sort_by` can do the job.

Comment: Remember when writing a `sort` function that if `a` sorts before `b` then `b` *must* sort after `a`. This sounds obvious, but it's not hard to introduce rock-paper-scissors type loops in your logic where `rock,paper,scissors` and `scissors,paper,rock` are both valid sort orders. That leads to inconsistent output.

Answer (score -1):

First, [fix your `sort_by` as per @tadman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53071682/14660).

```
backlog.sort_by!(&:effort)
```

> *So I KNOW there's an array of non-NULL objects there because that "6" on the first line of output is non-Null.*

You only checked the first element of `workingBacklog.backlog`. There could still be a `nil` somewhere further in your `backlog` array.

Look for `nil` with a `select.with_index`.

```
backlog.select.with_index { |obj,idx|
  puts "nil at #{idx}" if obj == nil
}
```

Here's an example that also reproduces the error.

```
backlog = [Opportunity.new(3, 4), nil]
puts backlog[0].effort
backlog.sort_by!(&:effort)

4    
/Users/schwern/tmp/test.rb:16:in `each': undefined method `effort' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/schwern/tmp/test.rb:16:in `sort_by'
    from /Users/schwern/tmp/test.rb:16:in `sort_by!'
    from /Users/schwern/tmp/test.rb:16:in `<main>'
```